# AWS Api Gateway- no integration defined for method

Tags: amazon-api-gateway

Though I have defined the integration when I try to deploy an api gateway I keep getting "No integration defined for method" error similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087890/no-integration-defined-for-method-choose-a-stage-where-your-api-will-be-deploy?rq=1

Here they have mentioned the reply as "Set up the integration method".

However I have set up integration method.
Attaching a screenshot, so what exactly is the problem in my case?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please make sure ALL of your methods for ALL of your resources have integrations  defined. Even if a single one is not defined, you are going to hit the error. Delete all methods that you don't intend to use.

Comment: Awesome! You could mark my answer as correct if you feel it was so it can be helpful to others :)

Comment: Thanks. I've been search for the solution for a few day. "+1"

Comment: This is also true for a serverless deployment. The deployment will fail and rollback if API Gateway is in that state, likely from console edits.